# error in multiplying and dividing userform input value in order to get a new range of values in column a

Tags: excel, vba

I received a runtime error 13 in this line

`"Cell.Value = (Cell.Value * UserForm2.InputBoxValue.Value) / 60"`

My userform is called `UserForm2` and the name of the textbox that garners input data from user is called `InputBoxValue`.

```
Sub plottinggraph()

    Dim LastRowOfA As Long, LastRowOfB As Long, LastRowOfG As Long
    Dim ColumnARngData As Range
    
    LastRowOfA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowOfB = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ColumnARngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:A" & LastRowOfA)
    
    For Each Cell In ColumnARngData
        Cell.Value = (Cell.Value * UserForm2.InputBoxValue.Value) / 60
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Check content of `InputBoxValue.Value` and content of `Cell.Value` at the moment the runtime error occurs.

Comment: I used debug.print(InputBoxValue.Value) and it came up empty. Why is it so?

Comment: Because at the moment you  execute the code, the InputBox is empty. Hard to tell why, but do you, by any chance, use the infamous command `Unload` to hide the form?

Comment: No, i didnt. Does Unload function prevents user from getting the data?

Comment: Using `Unload` will destroy the form object (and therefore all content is lost). When accessing `UserForm2.InputBoxValue` after an `Unload`-command, the VBA runtime will create a new (empty) Userform-Object (this is called "default instance"). It's a common mistake when using userforms  and SO is full with questions about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try avoid do math in raw data from objects. add some variable in declarated format. comment where i made changes

```
Sub plottinggraph()

    Dim LastRowOfA As Long, LastRowOfB As Long, LastRowOfG As Long
    Dim ColumnARngData As Range
    dim tbData as long    ' variable for textbox value, if you have float/double format just change        
    
    tbData = clng(UserForm2.InputBoxValue.Value) ' clng for sure
    if not isnumeric(tbData ) then msgbox "NaN",vbcritical,"" : end ' condition to check is tbdata is number

    LastRowOfA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowOfB = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ColumnARngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:A" & LastRowOfA)
    
    For Each Cell In ColumnARngData
        if not isnumeric(Cell.value) then msgbox "NaN",vbcritical,"" : end ' condition to check is cell value is number
        Cell.Value = (Cell.Value * tbData ) / 60
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

//edited

```
 Sub plottinggraph()

    Dim LastRowOfA As Long, LastRowOfB As Long, LastRowOfG As Long
    Dim ColumnARngData As Range
    Dim tbData As Double ' variable for textbox value, if you have float/double format just change
    Dim form As UserForm2 ' var for userform
    
    Set form = UserForm2
    If form.InputBoxValue.Value = "" Then ' condition for check is empty
       MsgBox "NaN", vbCritical, "": End '
    Else
       On Error Resume Next
       tbData = form.InputBoxValue.Value
       If Err Then MsgBox "NaN", vbCritical, "": End '
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    LastRowOfA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowOfB = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ColumnARngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:A" & LastRowOfA)
    
    For Each Cell In ColumnARngData
        If Not IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then MsgBox "NaN", vbCritical, "": End ' condition to check is cell value is number
        Cell.Value = (Cell.Value * tbData) / 60
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: It works!  I didnt know theres a function called "clng"! Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Your check for a numeric value is flawed. You convert the values with `cLng` - but that fails if the textbox is empty or contains a non-numeric string. You check for `isnumeric` is useless because at that point the value is already converted to a number.

Comment: true clng will not even work if object value is string. edited and add another condition